# Responsive tooltip button, with correct overflow

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple calendar with tooltip, when hovering on days it shows a description or festival that is celebrated on that day.
Here is css of tooltip:

```
.tooltiptext{
    display:none;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:200px;
    top: 5px;
    text-align:left;
    border-radius:6px;
    padding:5px ; 
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Demo of calendar: http://buhehe.de/kalender-2018/

Problem: on full width, with some months, for example in April the tooltip text box is not shown fully. I tried `overflow:visible` but it doesn't show the text box fully.

On mobile, and under 1000px width, everything is shown half or only 25%.
Is it possible to make my tooltip box responsive? In small screen showing correctly?

This page is of a similar calendar for which tooltip box correctly shows in small screen too: https://www.schulferien.org/kalender/2018/kalender_2018.html

I tried to write in .tooltiptext code: `Position:relative; top:5px;` but haven't solved the problem.

For example, it would be good: tooltip box in small width where only 2 month are shown in one line. A textbox of left month must be shown on right side, and box of right month must be shown on left side. Like in greater screen where only 3 month are shown. In full width, text boxes of most right months, must be shown on left side.